# How to get relative path of a file in a different library?

Tags: visual-studio, relative-path

I have two projects in my solution:

1. Echipieri.Data (database repository) -> Locations.txt
2. Echipieri.Web (ASP.NET MVC)

I want to read the locations file from Data but I can't figure out the relative path.

I tryed:

```
string path = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Locations.txt");
```

But it searches in `Echipieri.Web` not `Echipieri.Data`. How do I get it to search in `Echipieri.Data` folder?

Comment: is this an embedded resource, or a file that is included in the output?

Comment: @BrendanGreen I've set it's properties to include it in the output (not sure where the file is outputed to however is it in IIS Express or somewhere else?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is relative to the application/site that is running the code. You need to move your text file to Echipieri.Web and supply the path to the file, or its contents, to your data layer.